# How to dereference values with same name from props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I use to get values from props like this

```js
onSubmit = () => {
    const {
        id,
        client: {
            name,
            surname,
            address
        },
    } = this.props.release

    this.props.onSubmit(id, name, surname, address)
}
```

now I need to update the onSubmit call passing an additional arg, that in my props object is inside recipient, and the name is address. I can't do this:

```js
const {
    id,
    client: {
        name,
        surname,
        address
    },
    recipient: {
        address
    },
} = this.props.release

this.props.onSubmit(id, name, surname, address, < recipientAddress >)
```

because this conflicts with address inside client.
how can I solve this please?

Comment: proper term is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const {
  id,
  client: {
    name,
    surname,
    address
  },
  recipient: {
    address: recipientAddress
  },
} = this.props.release

this.props.onSubmit(id, name, surname, address, recipientAddress)
```

And then you can access the `address` property of `recipient` object by accessing `recipientAddress`

Comment: is there a way to assign a default to address: recipientAddress?

Comment: @user3174311 you mean to say assigning some default if address doesn't exist in the object? If so, you can do something like this-->  recipient: {address: recipientAddress='some default address'} = this.props.release

Comment: what if recipient does not exists at all?

Comment: @user3174311 even if the recipient object doesn't exist the value of recipientAddress will equal to 'some default address' because we set this as default for recipientAddress in the  comment above

Answer (score 0):

You do net need to use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), just use props as is:

```js
onSubmit = () => {
    this.props.onSubmit(
        this.props.release.id,
        this.props.release.client.name, 
        this.props.release.client.surname,
        this.props.release.client.address, 
        this.props.release.recipient.address
    )
}
```

Comment: Please don't do it :-(

Comment: @DennisVash not my proudest answer.